# Exponential function - inequality

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Consider the function $$ f:\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \frac{e^x -1}{x}$$

Now consider this inequality that came up in the textbook when talking about how to continue that function at $x=0$.

$$ |x| \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{|x|^{k-2}}{k!} \leq
|x| \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}$$

**How is this true?** Let $x=10$, then if we plug it in:

$$ \frac{10^1}{2!} + \frac{10^2}{3!} + ... \leq \frac{10}{2!} + \frac{10}{3!}+... $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we are considering that $x \to 0$, we may assume $|x|\le1$. Then
$$
|x|^{k-2}\le 1
$$ giving
$$
 |x| \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{|x|^{k-2}}{k!} \leq
|x| \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}.
$$
Taking $x=10$ is not appropriate.

Comment: That makes sense, I wish they would have just noted somewhere: Consider $|x| \leq 1$. Sometimes I feel like a few words here and there do make the reading much more fluent.

Comment: @plsmakemedomath Yes, I understand your point of view.

Answer (score 3):

One must assume that $|x|\le1$. Since you are dealing with a neighbourhood of $0$, it can be done.

But the book should still have made the assumption explicit.